# Angular Form with Multiple Nested Form Groups

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, formgroups, angular16

Why is this not working? The button is not working and I suspect the form is not working either.  This is just an example of a much larger more complex form/formGroup I am working.  The larger case is using angular materials and gives many errors related to not finding the second nested form group and `Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl`.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Multiple From Groups</h1>

    <div [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
      <input formControlName="a">
      <div formGroupName="nestedGroupOne">
        <input formControlName="b">
      </div>
      <div formGroupName="nestedGroupTwo">
        <input formControlName="c">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">log form</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myForm = this.fb.group({
    a: 'a',
    nestedGroupOne: this.fb.group({
      b: 'b',
    }),
    nestedGroupTwo: this.fb.group({
      c: 'c',
    }),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  logForm() {
    console.log('xyz');
    console.log(this.myForm);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Code written on stackblitz, with angular 16

Expect one form with multiple nested groups.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided seems correct in terms of creating the form groups and form controls. However, there is an issue with the way you're trying to bootstrap the Angular application.

It appears that you're trying to bootstrap the application using a method called bootstrapApplication, which is not a standard Angular method for bootstrapping an application. In a typical Angular application, you would use the `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule() method` to bootstrap your app module.

Here's how you should bootstrap your Angular application:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Multiple Form Groups</h1>
    <div [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
      <input formControlName="a">
      <div formGroupName="nestedGroupOne">
        <input formControlName="b">
      </div>
      <div formGroupName="nestedGroupTwo">
        <input formControlName="c">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">log form</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myForm = this.fb.group({
    a: 'a',
    nestedGroupOne: this.fb.group({
      b: 'b',
    }),
    nestedGroupTwo: this.fb.group({
      c: 'c',
    }),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  logForm() {
    console.log('xyz');
    console.log(this.myForm);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [App],
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

In the updated code, I've created an AppModule and used `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` to bootstrap the application. Additionally, I've included the BrowserModule in the imports of the AppModule to properly bootstrap the app in a browser environment.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue, not sure why the app I am working on still does not like it but probably a similar issue of not importing something that needs to be imported.  Thank You, The Life-Time-Learner!

Comment: If this answer is useful, you can accept this answer or upvote the answer